# When do pairs of functions constitute a functor?

Tags: category-theory

Suppose we have a given category $D$ and we are given a pair of functions $(f,g)$ where the domain of $f$ are the objects of $D$ and the domain of $g$ are the arrows of $D$. This pair may, or may not, constitute a functor from D to some other (unspecified) category.

My question concerns what general methods/tests/procedures (if any) one can use to determine whether or not a given pair of functions constitutes a functor from a given category $D$. Perhaps no general methods exist, or perhaps each case needs to be dealt with very individually, but that is what I am trying to find out.

Comment: Test the definig properties, perheps?

Answer (score 1):

Check against the definition of functor:

- If $\phi$ is an arrow from $X$ to $Y$, then $g(\phi)$ must be an arrow from $f(X)$ to $f(Y)$ (covariant case)
- $g(\operatorname{id}_X)=\operatorname{id}_{f(X)}$ for all $X$
- If arrows $\phi,\psi$ can be composed, then so can $g(\phi),g(\psi)$, and $g(\phi\circ\psi)=g(\phi)\circ g(\psi)$